# Project Sync-ing doesn't work in tablet as in the phones Qfield app

Tags: error, qfieldsync, relation, qfield-cloud

I have a project in QGIS and I'd made some relations in it, but one of (a non geometric layer, named Evaluate, which is based on a Vector layers (point) order number. This layer contains trees) those didn't want to work in QField (I tried to check it just in the tablet...).
I tried it for a while, when I'd checked it in the phone too. And it worked!
Could anyone met with this scenario, or why it should be?